# Left vlookup error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to do left vlookup here. I understand that I have some values that cannot be found but I don't understand why is there still error of Application-defined or object defined error popping out in the middle of the loop. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
 With Sheet3
 x = 2
 Do Until IsEmpty(.Range("E" & x).value)
 look = .Range("E" & x).value
 result = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), 
 WorksheetFunction.Match(look, Sheet2.Range("B:B"), 0))
   If Not IsError(result) Then
       .Range("F" & x).value = result
   Else
       .Range("F" & x).value = " "
   End If
   x = x + 1
Loop
End With
```

Comment: Please specify "I understand that I have some values that cannot be found"

Comment: means that some of the values cannot be found in vlookup and i want to return it as blank

Comment: At what cell value does the error occur?

Comment: cell value 23. Its the value where cannot be found by vlookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, the IsErrror function returns true if a Variant holds the vbError value. This value isn't assigned to the `Result` variable, even if it is a variant, when the error occurs in not finding the Match. You would have to capture that error using the `On Error Goto ...` method.

It isn't such a big deal. Your code might look like this.

```
Result = ""
On Error Resume Next
Result = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), _
         WorksheetFunction.Match(look, Sheet2.Range("B:B"), 0))
.Range("F" & x).Value = Result
```

If an error results, the variable Result will retain the value it had before. Therefore it is set to "" before the function. So you don't need to test if there was an error.

In the process of writing this code I found that you had also missed the underscore at the line break of the Index function.

Comment: This method worked for vlookup but why not for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this array formula do the job?

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW‌​S($G$1:$G1)))
```

it is on rows 1 to 8